# requests python lib adding in Accept header

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests

so I have made a request to a server with pythons request library. The code looks like this (it uses an adapter so it needs to match a certain pattern)

```
def getRequest(self, url, header):
    """
    implementation of a get request
    """

    conn = requests.get(url,  headers=header)
    newBody = conn.content
    newHeader = conn.headers
    newHeader['status'] = conn.status_code

    response  = {"Headers" : newHeader, "Body" : newBody.decode('utf-8')}

    self._huddleErrors.handleResponseError(response)
    return response
```

the header parameter I am parsing in is this

```
{'Authorization': 'OAuth2 handsOffMyToken', 'Accept': 'application/vnd.huddle.data+json'}
```

however I am getting an xml response back from the server. After checking fiddler I see the request being sent is:

```
Accept-Encoding: identity
Accept: */*
Host: api.huddle.dev
Authorization: OAuth2 HandsOffMyToken
Accept: application/vnd.huddle.data+json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
User-Agent: python-requests/1.2.3 CPython/3.3.2 Windows/2008ServerR2
```

As we can see there are 2 Accept Headers! The requests library is adding in this Accept:* / * header which is throwing off the server. Does anyone know how I can stop this?

Comment: Overwriting both headers works fine for me on python 2.7.5. Maybe it's 3.3 problem?

Comment: it seems like [the bug](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/821#issuecomment-17791431). Try to update `requests` or use `b'Accept'` as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments it seems this is a problem with the requests library in 3.3. In requests there are default headers (which can be found in the utils folder). When you don't specify your own headers these default headers are used. However if you specify your own headers instead requests tries to merge the headers together to make sure you have all the headers you need.

The problem shows its self in  def request() method in sessions.py. Instead of merging all the headers it puts in its headers and then chucks in yours. For now I have just done the dirty hack of removing the accept header from the default headers found in util

Comment: Correct, this is a Requests bug. We are aware of it and there is an [outstanding Pull Request](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1338) that will fix the issue. This can't be merged immediately because it changes the Python3 API, so we need to wait for a major release.

Comment: In the meantime, I am keeping [this branch](https://github.com/Lukasa/requests/tree/keytype) (which contains the fix) up to date with master until that merge occurs.

Comment: Hi zidsal. I have exactly the same issue as you described, that's an additional header "Accept-Encoding: identity". I'm still not clear how you fixed it. Could you paste the code you modified in util.py? Thanks.

Comment: ok Youshui you have 2 choices here the correct choice is to use the branch Lukasa posted. The second option is to nastily hack away at the requests library, and stop it merging your dict with the default dict (or you can add your Accept-Encoding to the default dict).

I would strongly advice you to not do what I did and use Lukasa's changes instead.